# ULong Jackson (de)serializer

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have an endpoint that receives an DTO into the body.
The DTO has a ULong attribute that the Jackson do not parse (deserialize) when I request the
endpoint with postman.

Also, I try to create my custom serializer?

```
class ULongSerializer: StdSerializer<ULong>{
    override fun serializer(value: ULong, gen: JsonGenarator, provader: SerializerProvider){
    gen.writeStartObject()
    gen.writeNumber(value) //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    gen.writeEndObject
  }
    
}
```

neither write number method do not support ULong, nor another methods like write field.

Can someone give me some tips to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

`ULong` is a class and you [may write](https://pl.kotl.in/hWY-AeLrW) Jackson serializer/deserializer for it, but a field of this type is compiled to bytecode as a field of primivite `long` type. So values exceeding `Long.MAX_VALUE` would be serialized/deserialized incorrectly (as negative), and custom serializer/deserializer won't help you.

Take a look at `kotlinx.serialization`. It have OOTB experimental support for unsigned integer types. See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#experimental-support-for-inline-classes-ir-only

Comment: Thank you for helping